# Properties of fat Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

Let $C$ be a fat Cantor set and $\mathbb{Q}$ is set of rationals.

Q) Is it true that closure of intersection of $C$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is $C$ that is
$$\overline{ C\cap \mathbb{Q}}=C?$$

Q) If the above is not true then can we atleast say that  $\overline{ C\cap \mathbb{Q}}$ is a set of positive Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Actually there _exists_ a fat Cantor set $C$ with $C\cap\Bbb Q=\emptyset$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ... for **fat** Cantor set, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287866/fat-cantor-set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For David's comment:  Start with $\big[{-\sqrt2},\sqrt2\,\big]$.
Enumerate the rationals in $\big({-\sqrt2},\sqrt2\,\big)$.  At the $n$th stage: remove a short interval (with irrational endpoints) containing the $n$th rational (if that rational remains). Result: $C\cap \mathbb Q = \varnothing$.

On the other hand, if you always remove intervals with rational endpoints, then the set of those endpoints remains as a subset of $C$ and is dense in $C$.  So in that case $\overline{C \cap \mathbb Q} = C$.

Comment: Wow. I learnt a lot about fat Cantor set with this. Many many thanks