# Relationship between dense sets, open sets and Lebesgue measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open ball. Let $D\subset B$ be dense in $B$. Also assume $D\subset U$. Can anything positive be said about $U$ "almost" containing $B$? I know that generally $B\subset U$ is not true.

But maybe it is true that $U$ always contains a set $T \subset B$ such that $|B\setminus T|=0$? Any other result is also appreciated. If it helps, assume that $U$ is bounded.

Comment: For a counterexample in the $n=1$ case, take the complement in $B$ of a "fat Cantor set": see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287866/fat-cantor-set).  Easily adabpted to get counterexamples for general $n$.

Comment: A good source on this is Oxtoby’s book Measure and category, Springer-Verlag.

Comment: If $D$ is, say countable, (or more generally, any dense measure $0$ set in $B$) then an open subset of it can have arbitrarily small measure, by definition.