# Is there a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which has positive Lebesgue-measure and no interior points?

Tags: measure-theory

As the title says, I would like to know how to construct a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which does not have interior points but positive Lebesgue-measure?

As a hint, it is given $(0,1)\setminus K$...

Comment: what is an inner point? do you mean interior point?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My english!.. I meant a point, for which there is a neighboorhoud within the set.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set#Nowhere_dense_sets_with_positive_measure this may help you.

Comment: what is $k$ in the hint?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed. A more generalized version of the construction of the Cantor set is something called a "[fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Cantor_set)." As with the usual Cantor set, it is compact and has no interior points, but unlike the usual Cantor set, it has positive measure.

In fact, for any $0<a<1,$ there is a fat Cantor set of measure $1-a$. See Brian M. Scott's excellent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141521/28900) for more details, but the idea is to remove the middle $\frac{a}3$ of each component interval at each stage, rather than the entire middle third.

Comment: Could you please have a look on this: http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/labs/paperfoldinglab/fatcantorset.html Why does this set have no interior points?

Comment: Well, notice what happens at each stage. In the first stage, we remove an interval of length $\frac14,$ leaving us two intervals of length $\frac38.$ In the second stage, we remove an interval of length $\frac16,$ leaving us $4$ intervals of length $\frac5{32}$. In the third stage, we remove $4$ intervals of length $\frac1{64},$ leaving us $8$ intervals of length $\frac9{128}.$ In the fourth stage, we remove $8$ intervals of length $\frac1{256},$ leaving $16$ intervals of length $\frac{17}{512}$. And so on....

Comment: More generally, it can be shown (by induction) that after the $n$th stage, there are $2^n$ intervals of length $\dfrac{2^n+1}{2^{2n+1}}.$ It can be shown that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n+1}{2^{2n+1}}=0,$$ so given any positive length $\ell,$ there is some stage at which no interval of length $\ell$ can lie within the set at that stage, and so no such interval can lie within the fat Cantor set. Since this holds for all positive lengths $\ell,$ then the fat Cantor set contains no open interval.